# Facebook like button being clipped

Tags: css, facebook

maybe you can help me. My Facebook button was working fine but now seems to have two problems:

1) The send button is no longer visible. Is this a change from Facebook?

2) It is being cropped by my page container even thou I set overflow to auto (I even tried visible)

My website is http://easydiablo3.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, this is a Facebook bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/299191993489218?browse=search_4f9b0114e02557f41110709

2) Position looks fine to me in Chrome except for the overlapping banner ad: http://screencast.com/t/1FRbfxbk

Comment: I mean the like box is being clipped, not the actual button (the box that comes up when you click on the like button)

Comment: Thumbs up for finding a chrome-specific bug on my layout too :P

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. If I make your .overflowAuto element overflow: visible the comment flyout is completely visible.

Comment: Thanks, must have missed that!